# How can I access self referential property in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am very new to sqlalchemy 0.9. In my model class I create self referential integrity.my code is as follows:

## model.py:

```
class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = "employee"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
  name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)

            manager_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("employee.id",
                                          use_alter=True,
                                          name="fk_manager_id",
                                          onupdate="CASCADE",
                                          ondelete="RESTRICT"))


  def __init__(self, name, workstation_id, phone_extension):
    self.name = name
    self.workstation_id = workstation_id
    self.phone_extension = phone_extension
```

So manager_id refer to id property. Now the problem is how can I access manager name which is name property in Employee class using manager_id property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to define a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html) using [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships):

```
class Employee(Base):
    ...
    manager = relationship("Employee", remote_side=[id])
```

You can also extend this using backrefs and change directions as you please. Refer to above documentation for extended information.